# Panel drawing ellipse with background image

Tags: c#, drawing, panel, ellipse

I have an application which draws an eclipse onto a panel.
This panel is called: map, inside the constructor I do this:

```
gMap = map.CreateGraphics();
```

Then inside an foreach loop, I loop through an arraylist until I find an value and then I do this:

```
gMap.Clear(Color.White);
map.BackgroundImage = Map_Application.Properties.Resources.WH2F;
gMap.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(Color.Red), xCoor, yCoor, 30, 30);
break;
```

My problem is that it only shows the ellipse really briefly (in a flash), when I don't set the background image the ellipse does stay there but the panel has an white background.

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What I can think here is, you are drawing ellipse and then when a background Image added to panel Windows dose Refresh() / Paint().

At that time your previously drawn graphics are cleared for that panel.

So, if you draw your ellipse in Panel Paint event it will stay there.

Hope it helps..!!